# model.to(torch.device("cuda")) Error - Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have been trying to run the code from here in Visual Studio Code

https://www.kaggle.com/abhishek/melanoma-detection-with-pytorch?scriptVersionId=35193166

and I get an error for  model.to(torch.device("cuda"))
and it also says AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

I am very sure Cuda is enabled for Torch (I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650)

[cuda installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulral.png)

Here is a part of the code as well

```
training_data_path = ".."
model_path = ".."
df = pd.read_csv("..")
device = "cuda"
epochs = 50
train_bs = 32
valid_bs = 16

df_train = df[df.kfold != fold].reset_index(drop=True)
df_valid = df[df.kfold == fold].reset_index(drop=True)

model = SEResNext50_32x4d(pretrained = "imagenet")
model.to(torch.device("cuda"))
```

I do not understand why it doesn't recognize it.
Please help.

Comment: "Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled" means exactly what is says -- the Pytorch version you have installed has not been built with CUDA support. Whether you install CUDA or not will make absolutely no difference. You need to find and install a different version of PytTorch

Comment: I used the command "conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch" from the official website, which is supposed to install latest version for both. What am I supposed to change or to do different to make it work?